# Moving data across pages in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to transfer data from one screen to another. What I have now does work, but I want to be able to have icon in
the AppBar that will only go to the second page, and not take any arguments. For now I have this:

**FIRST PAGE**

This is the icon on the first page that adds the list tile arguments to the Cart screen (and only adds , it doesn't push the Cart screen, that
should be done below in the appbar.

```
child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                       
                        onPressed: () => MaterialPageRoute(
                              
                              builder: (context) =>
                                  Cart(person.name, person.surname),
                            )),
```

Below in the scaffold I have this in the AppBar, the icon that should only push the Cart screen, and not any other values.

```
IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart, color: Colors.white),
            //this will be the cart window ontap, change icon to something better
            onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                        Cart(//there should be arguments here, but I just want to go to Cart screen, the arguments were added in the first icon))),
```

This Cart class requires arguments (from the second page, like personName, personSurname), but I just want to be able to push
the second screen, and not have any arguments on there. It is the small cart icon in the appbar.

**SECOND PAGE**

Here is the second page (sudo cart screen) that should just take in the arguments from the first one.

```
 class Cart extends StatefulWidget {
  
  final String personName;
  final String personSurname;
  Cart(this.personName, this.personSurname);

  @override
  _CartState createState() => _CartState();
}

class _CartState extends State<Cart> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Cart'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: Container(
              child: Text('${widget.personName}, ${widget.personSurname}'))),
    );
  }
}
```

My issue is that I want to have the 2 separate functions for the cart. First one is on the first page where first icon
only adds the whatever argument I want to the cart, and the second icon in the app bar of first page just pushes the Cart screen.

In the second screen, I just want to have whatever data pushed from the first page.

Comment: I think you contradict yourself in your questions? If I understand this correctly you only want to navigate to the shopping cart page with the 2nd icon but don't take any data with you? It would only make sense if you save your Arguments on the first page with e.g. setState() and pass the Arguments with the second ItemButton to the second page though. Please explain better so we can help you.

Comment: Basically the first icon button should add that data to the 'cart' screen (the data from the list tile in this case), and the second one, the icon on the app bar should only route to that screen (second, cart screen) if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

1. Declare two variables above:

```
String name = '';
String surname = '';
```

2. Assign your data to them:

```
child: IconButton(
         icon: Icon(Icons.add),
         onPressed: () {
           name = person.name;
           surname = person.surname;
         },
```

3. And use them as arguments:

```
IconButton(
    icon: Icon(Icons.add_shopping_cart, color: Colors.white),
    onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (BuildContext context) =>  Cart(name, surname))
                ),
```